# No static files - .net core host on nginx ubuntu server 18.04 with custom domain

Tags: nginx, .net-core, ubuntu-18.04, ubuntu-server

**Problem:** No static files loaded (404)

**Description:** Hosting a .net core MVC application on nginx through reverse proxy. It has been configured to support SSL with letsencrypts certificates and configured so that it can host multiple websites by adding their configurations in `sites-available` folder.

**Configuration file:**

```
server {
        listen   80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name mydomain.com *.mydomain.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass              http://localhost:5000;
                proxy_http_version      1.1;
                proxy_set_header        Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header        Connection keep-alive;
                proxy_set_header        Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass      $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                root /var/www/mydomain.com/htdocs;
        }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
```

**Attempts:** I have tried with different variations of `root` and `try_files` setup. Also, tried adding a named separate `location` section to bind it through proxy for `try_files`. In order to test if the files are there in the first place I have run `curl` to files location on `localhost:5000` and it is definitely there.

**Current state:** The site does load when domain is visited, but it is throwing 404 for each and every static file. I have in my configuration section of the app `app.UseStaticFiles();` so that's not missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have specified only 1 rule as reverse proxy, even if you specified a `root` property, it is never used.
What we need to do is to use 2 rules that one handles 404 from another one:

```
server {
    listen   80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name mydomain.com *.mydomain.com;

    location / {
        root /var/www/mydomain.com/htdocs;
        error_page 404 @app;
    }

    location @app {
        proxy_pass              http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_http_version      1.1;
        proxy_set_header        Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header        Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header        Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass      $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

The reason why it is configured to use the app as fallbacks for static files rather than using static files as fallbacks for the app is that, if the app has some custom 404 page that the code is not 404, the static files would not be used.

And then you would be able to remove the `UseStaticFiles` from your application.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I have tried this and the response from nginx is now 403 Forbidden. Do I need to set some additional permissions perhaps?

Comment: You need to make sure the owner of `/var/www/mydomain.com/htdocs` is the user that is used with nginx. For example if the directory is owned by root, you need to put `user root;` on the top of the whole `nginx.conf`

Comment: The only thing missing was try_files that points to the @app. Everything else was perfectly ok with the settings you provided. Thanks for the help.